# automatic AirPrint IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, airprint

I need to AirPrint in Xcode in the background without users interaction. I do not care if I have to use a 3rd party framework to do this. Here is the code I have but requires the user's interaction.

```
 NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TextField.text];

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate = self;


    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"PrintJob";
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;


    UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
    textFormatter.startPage = 0;
    textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0);
    textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
    pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;


void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};


    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

If any one could help that would be great!

Comment: you want to print automatic without any action?

Comment: Have you looked here?: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPrintInteractionController/printToPrinter:completionHandler:

Comment: Yes @DarjiJigar thats what I want to do

Comment: @Connor have you try this code in viewdidload method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a video that helped a lot](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/718/)! It was the wwdc video for iOS 8 they just introduced new way to print without using the UIPrintInteractionController. Here it is.

```
    -(IBAction)print:(id)sender{

      NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hey this is a test lets hope it works!"];

      UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
      pic.delegate = self;


      UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
      printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
      printInfo.jobName = @"PrintJob";
      pic.printInfo = printInfo;


      UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
      textFormatter.startPage = 0;
      textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0);
      textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
      pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
      pic.showsPageRange = YES;
//save your printer using code also in video. 

      UIPrinter *SavedPrinterUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                             objectForKey:@"SavedPrinter"];
      [pic printToPrinter:SavedPrinterUserDefaults
        completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
          if (completed && !error)
            NSLog(@"YAYA! it printed");
        }];

    }
```

I hope this helps any one who has the same problem. [Here is more to read about what you can do with this new API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrinter_class/)!